# What does this output mean?

Tags: ftp, notepad++

I am using `FTP` from `Notepad++` to connect to host. On getting connected I am getting following output in a window named `NppFTP-Output`

```
220---------- Welcome to Pure-FTPd [privsep] ----------
220-You are user number 17 of 500 allowed.
220-Local time is now 12:55. Server port: 21.
220-This is a private system - No anonymous login
220 You will be disconnected after 3 minutes of inactivity.
```

My question is about second line which says `220-You are user number 17 of 500 allowed.`, What does this mean? Does this mean I can connect only 500 times to the server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is telling you that 500 simultaneous connections (users) may be made at any point in time. When you connected, you were the 17th user connected (assuming every user has one connection).